# Getting very weird error "SyntaxError: '...' expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier, react-map-gl

I am trying to pass a prop down to a REACTMAPGL in react, I am calling the method *displayMarkers()* which returns an array for JSX Elements.

The problem revolves mainly around why I am getting the error in this specific project. I created the component just fine and have been able to use it in a different project locally. But It seems to be related to Typescript or prettier maybe in the current codebase I am working on.

Here is the error

```
10% building 3/13 modules 10 active /Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.jsℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
95% emitting Prettier✖ ｢wdm｣: SyntaxError: '...' expected. (122:12)
  120 |           onViewportChange={setViewPort}
  121 |           style={{ left: 120, top: 50 }}
> 122 |           {displayMarkers()}
      |            ^
  123 |         />
  124 |         <NavigationControl showCompass={false} style={{ left: 140, top: 70 }} />
  125 |         <MapControl visibleMap={visibleMap} onMapChange={handleMapChange} />
    at t (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:1:285)
    at Object.parse (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/parser-typescript.js:14:180461)
    at Object.parse (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:9739:19)
    at coreFormat (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:13252:23)
    at format (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:13510:73)
    at formatWithCursor (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:13526:12)
    at /Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:44207:15
    at Object.format (/Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier/index.js:44226:12)
    at /Volumes/workplace/opsPortal/src/LeoAccessOperationsPortalStaticWebsite/node_modules/prettier-webpack-plugin/index.js:70:47
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
```

Here is the full JSX being returned:

```
if (transformRequest) {
    return (
    <div>
        <ReactMapGL
          {...viewport}
          width="80%"
          height={'65vh'}
          transformRequest={transformRequest}
          mapStyle={visibleMap}
          onViewportChange={setViewPort}
          style={{ left: 120, top: 50 }}
          {displayMarkers()}
        />
        <NavigationControl showCompass={false} style={{ left: 140, top: 70 }} />
        <MapControl visibleMap={visibleMap} onMapChange={handleMapChange} />
      </div>
    );
  } else return <div>{<h1>Loading...</h1>}</div>;
};
```

I tried putting a {/*prettier-ignore*/} over the {displayMarkers()}, but then the exact same error happens, but it points to the {/*prettier-ignore*/}.

Note: The code compiles if I add the spread operator, but it breaks the the component because the component is expected an array, but it gets an object I think.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely does not like the fact that you aren't placing an attribute name before the function, like so.

```html
<Prop key={func()} />
```

---

To fix it, you need to add an attribute before `displayMarkers()`, like below.

```html
<ReactMapGL displayMarkers={displayMarkers()} />
```

*Note: The rest of the keys are not in `ReactMapGL`, as that would not make the code very readable.*

---

If `displayMarkers()` was supposed to be the text displayed in the prop, then you need to change your prop to the following.

```html
<ReactMapGL>{displayMarkers()}</ReactMapGL>
```

*Note: The rest of the keys are not in `ReactMapGL`, as that would not make the code very readable.*